# How to show a title-link in a view for authorized and hide it for unauthorized users?

Tags: views

I have a view with some fields and one of them is the title field. Now i need the feature that when an anonymous user views the view, the title is not linked to it´s content. When the user logs in, then the title should link to its content. How is it possible to realize that? I have more or less no php skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [template_preprocess_views_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_field/7) function in your module and rewrite output for this field for anonymous users.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view_field().
 */
 function mymodule_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars) {
   switch ($vars['view']->name) {
     case 'my_view_name':
       if ($vars['field']->options['id'] == 'my_field_name') {
         if (user_is_anonymous()) {
           $vars['output'] = strip_tags($vars['output']);
         }
       }
       break;
   }
 }
```

Comment: i used your code and put it in the template.php file - is that possible too? changed "mymodule" to the name of my theme, also "my_view_name" to the name of my view and "my_field_name" to "views-field-title" but it seems it doesn´t work for Drupal7

Comment: Please try to change "views-field-title" to "title"

Comment: Didn´t work either, you wrote "options['id']" but the name is a class, does this matter? And to use the code in template.php is ok?

Comment: It's okay to add this code in your theme. It should work. Can you debug if you use correct '$vars['view']->name' and '$vars['field']->options['id']'. You can use print_r or var_dump functions for these variables.

Comment: working now!!! thanks a lot! The view name was correct but the field name wasn´t, i corrected it and now it works perfectly.